# Match array in either 2d or 1d array

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I have an array called `answerArray` and I need to see if it matches one of 4 other arrays (Some which are 2d) ex:

```
var answerArray = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1];
var case1 = [
             [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
             [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
             [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1],
             [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
                               ];
var case2 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2];
var case3 = [
             [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
             [1, 3, 2, 2, 2]
                            ];
var case4 = [1, 4];
```

In that example answerArray has a match with case1 because case1 contains `[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]`

Here is a jsFiddle I did, seems like im close but still cannot get it: http://jsfiddle.net/dH2gx/1/

If you change answerArray to `[1,4]` you will see it says "Found Match on case 4"

Comment: Looks to me like you might need to call your function recursively such that if you have deep levels on nesting in an array which you are trying to evaluate, you can recursively call your function to look for a match.

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @intuitivepixel that is the exact way i am trying, doesn't work :/

Comment: If you changed it to `[3, 2]` would it then be supposed to match case1 and case3 or must a whole row be equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! For anyone in the future trying to do the same.

I made an array prototype "compare" seen here ([SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript))

```
for (var k = 1; k <= 4; k++) {//Loop number of cases
    var caseArray = eval("case" + k);//To be able to loop through each case
    for (var i = 0; i < caseArray.length; i++) {
        if ($.isArray(caseArray[i])) { //Check if array[i] is another array (2d array)
            if (caseArray[i].compare(answerArray)) { //Compare the nested array
                console.log("MATCH " + k);
                return k;
            }
        } else {//Not a 2d array
            if (caseArray.compare(answerArray)) {//compare the array
                console.log("MATCH " + k);
                return k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

surprisingly, you can use RegExp on numbers and arrays:

```
var answerArray = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1];
var case1 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
];
var case2 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2];
var case3 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    [1, 3, 2, 2, 2]
];
var case4 = [1, 4];

var hit=new RegExp("^"+answerArray+"$", "m");
var names=['case1', 'case2', 'case3', 'case4'];
var res=[case1, case2, case3, case4].map(function(a,b,c){

   return hit.test(a.join("\n")) && names[b];

}).filter(Boolean);


alert(res) // shows: "case1"
```

Answer (score -1):

NOOOO! EVAL()! MY NEMESIS!

Basically, the issue is that case4 is `undefined`. Your for loop uses `<=` so the iterator will go up to and include 4. When you enter your array comparison function, it doesn't enter the type-checking block because this is obviously not an instance of Array. But then, nothing causes it to return false.

Just move the type-checking up alongside the length comparison in `arraysEqual`, and return false. Oh, and...you're going to be asked many times not to use `eval` in your code. I'm going to assume that it was just a fast way of writing a test, though.

Comment: Im starting i at 1, so case4 gets evaluated. Also, I know about everyone saying i shouldn't use eval. It does what i need in this situation so for now i will use it :)

Comment: Alright, there's some confusion because your fiddle is different from your question: There's no case4 in your question.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. Fixed the question.